# deleting records with looped check boxes in PHP

Tags: php

below is part of my code where I'm trying to delete database records via a checkbox pick. The loop is how I get the data along with the check box. (code 1:) and (code 2:) is where I'm trying to delete the selected records.

As you may see in the loop there are 3 fields in the database and when deleting the records the code 2 checks only the match with first record which is `bname`. However my issue is I need to check whether all three database fields are matched before deleting from the system.
To explain the issue further;

```
bname | bvariant | bsku
-----------------------
apple |red       | 20g
apple |green     | 30g
```

The current code looks at the match with "apple" and deleted all two data rows. But if the use has picked row no 1 then I need the code to be adjusted to check the match with the database for all three fields, in which case only apple, red, 20g will be deleted. I have added `AND bvariant='$wec2' AND     bsku='$wec3'"` to code 2 but seems it doesn't work. Pls help.

**Code 1:**

```
while ($reK = mysqli_fetch_array($runBrands))
{
$wec = $reK['bname']; $wec2 = $reK['bvariant']; $wec3 = $reK['bsku'];
    echo "<tr class='brndTab'>";
    echo "<td class='brndTab'>".$reK["bname"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='brndTab'>".$reK["bvariant"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='brndTab1'>".$reK["bsku"]."</td>";
    echo "<td class='brc'><input type='checkbox' name='delz[]' value='$wec' ></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

**Code 2:**

```
if(isset($_POST['delz'])) 
{
foreach($_POST['delz'] as $we)
  {
$Mo = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM brands WHERE bname ='$we' AND bvariant='$wec2' AND     bsku='$wec3'");
  }
}
```

Comment: Why won't you add some numeric, auto-increment ID? It's common practice.

Comment: can you just put the auto-incremental ID on the value so that you won't have to match three items when deleteing?

Answer (score 0):

Your variables $wec2 and $wec3 are not initialized in your Code 2. You have to submit them to as hidden values in Code 1.

But as the previous commenters already suggested. Best way would be to use a primary key.